# Apache won't start after OSX Yosemite upgrade

Tags: macos

I installed Apache 2.2 using Homebrew on OSX 10.9 and it was working fine until I upgraded to Yosemite this weekend.

`sudo apachectl start`
`ps aux | grep httpd`
`ps aux | grep apache`
`sudo /usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.27/bin/httpd -k start`
They all return nothing.

`sudo apachectl` returns:

```
Usage: /usr/local/Cellar/httpd22/2.2.27/bin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                                              [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                                              [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                                              [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S]
```

Any idea what file I could look at to see if there is any error? [MAMP Pro seems to have similar issue which is fixed by renaming envvars to _envvars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201280/apache-not-starting-on-mamp-pro). I tried it and it didn't work.

Please let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should have done this first but I finally took a look at `/usr/local/var/log/apache2/error_log` and I saw this:

```
[Tue Jan 27 14:56:07 2015] [error] (2)No such file or directory: could not create /usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid
[Tue Jan 27 14:56:07 2015] [error] httpd: could not log pid to file /usr/local/var/run/apache2/httpd.pid
```

Obviously that was the issue... I created the folder `/usr/local/var/run/apache2/` and voilà!

Comment: Would really like to know the root cause of why we need to do this

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
brew update    

brew doctor    

brew reinstall php53 --with-mysql --with-pgsql --with-apache    

sudo apachectl -k restart
```

If you want you can see the complete post here:

http://benedmunds.com/php/2014/10/16/fixing-homebrew-php-apache-after-yosemite/

Comment: Thanks Jorge for the comment. I should have said that I already tried that (well, not reinstalling the whole thing 'cause I think it wasn't necessary) as this was the first result on Google.

Comment: I also have an issue with Yosemite and I resolve it with brew doctor.
As you wrote, take a look to the logs file should be the first thing to do.